# How does buying back stock affect a company's credit spread?

Tags: finance, credit

How does buying back stock affect a company's credit spread?  Would it cause it to get smaller?  Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: isn't that a very individual thing. In my opinion that would depend on the company in general. Or are you looking for some mathematical model ?

Answer (score 5):

All else being equal, buying back stock would cause a company's credit spread to widen (increase). This is because a share buyback involves shrinking the firm's assets (spending cash to buy back the stock) and shrinking equity/retained earnings, while leaving the liabilities unchanged (or increasing them in the case of a leveraged buy back). This is an increase in leverage, which would leave the firm more exposed to bankruptcy (and hence credit risk).

Comment: Worth noting: dividends have the same effect.  (Stock buybacks are often considered to be in lieu of dividends since the tax consequences are better).